# Time-sequential option in Stereo Mode is missing

Tags: stereoscopy

I'm trying to render an active-shutter or time-sequential 3D video with Blender 2.77a. 
I enabled Stereo 3D mode on the 'render layers' tab under Views, but under the Render tab under the Output section, the option for time-sequential rendering is not visible. It is visible however under the "Set Stereo 3D" option for the window display.

[image: Time-sequential option is missing]

I have a MSI R9390 GPU. I don't have a 3D monitor, but I'm assuming this isn't necessary for rendering.

Any idea why this option is missing?

Thanks