# 3D Stereo Active shutter vision LCS glasses realtime viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, stereoscopy

Is it possible (or maybe already implemented by someone) to configure the viewport to display stereoscopically at a set frequency dependent on the given screen refresh rate, while having the frequency channeled out as "sound" through the sound card (or maybe over IR or bluetooth) so to sync a stock pair of [Liquid Crystal Shutter 3D glasses (LCS)](https://cmst.curtin.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2016/05/2012-28-woods-helliwell-cross-compatibility_of_shutter_glasses.pdf) like [SegaScope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_System#/media/File:Sega-Masters-Sys-3D-Glasses.jpg)  or equivalent stock or "hacked" alternatives ? 
[Hacking example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RZFwZqvuyM&t=7m30s),
[better hacking](http://computernerdkev.heliohost.org/rainbowglasses/index.htm),
[Screen compatibility info pdf](https://cmst.curtin.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2016/05/2006-30.pdf)

or maybe directly [over VGA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5wu9gmshr4&t=1m14s) 
and [more good archaic info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3Wa6HYjqQw&t=5m45s) and [SegaScope alternative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhsJSxqLFWE&t=2m40s)

or maybe, since it's a monotone oscillation that's driving a binary outcome (left/right) ON/OFF, and a known frequency (if the max source refresh rate is applied and FPS is stable) it could be calibrated/synced manually without any direct power or initialization from the PC-GPU.

Maybe avoid [Quad-buffered (aka CrystalEyes)](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/vmd-1.9.1/ug/node101.html) [Quad buffering 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Quad_buffering) by NOT presenting the SAME, spatially displaced, image to both eyes, since in this "time-sequential" case, it isn't actually doable. It would make more sense to intermittently display realtime frames from each of the viewports (realtime-sequence).

[NVIDIA Fast Sync](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpUX8ZNkn2U&t=4m18s) ...and I'm on AMD, but the process can't differ much

[Clean (simplified) explanation of Nvidias' pipes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTYz4UgzCCU)

[Myths and Misconceptions of Frame Pacing / Alen Ladavac, Croteam / Reboot Develop Blue 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0zT8YSSFzw)

[CRU Custom resolution and screen framerate overclocking utility, which could come into play](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) and [Guide](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-peripheral/how-overclock-your-monitor-3635779/)

Comment: relevant, but not particularly useful https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/render/workflows/multiview/usage.html#display-mode

Comment: Begs this question that I'm not asking because I can't even enable the time-sequential mode, though this pertains to recording and my question is about pure realtime viewing (eventually recording) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60669/time-sequential-option-in-stereo-mode-is-missing